# How to resize table heights in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

I'm trying to edit a table in *LibreOffice Writer* so that the rows are each their own designated and precise height. I've managed that for the *columns* by going to **Table** > **Table Properties...** then selecting the **Columns** tab (as pictured below) but I cannot find a similar option for rows.
[image: Editing column width.]
Is there a way of editing row height without dragging the borders (which makes the result invariably imprecise)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-clik on the row you want to modify, go to **Row** and select **Height...**

[image: Pop-up menu > Row > Height...]

Deselect "Dynamic adjustment" and enter the desired height. (Please note that actual English terms may differ).

[image: Row height dialog box]

Tried it just now with LibreOffice 4.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know why I didn't try it that way in the first place. :-) Cheers!

Comment: Although it accepts `cm` it always shows `"` - how can one change that?

Comment: @Sadik, in LibreOffice Writer, go to **Tools** > **Options**, select under **LibreOffice Writer**, **General** and there choose the measurement unit you wish.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the row(s)
2. Right click > Size > Row Height
3. (uncheck 'Fit to size' for max flexibility) Either click on '+' or '-', OR edit height.